# How to select only part of a listview based on different requirements by the user?

Tags: android, listview, select, display

I am trying to develop an android mobile application whereby i am required to display part of a listviews which has at least 100 items.
Now i,being the admin of a college,i has listed 100 subjects to be taught.(all to be listed in a listview.All of the subjects have a point and in order for a strudent to apply for this course he/she need to have exact of higher points.An indicative sample is below:
English:24
Spanish:16
MAths:28
Science:26
French:16
Management:22
Law:30
Asian Language:10

Now the student needs to enter his/her point and based(EXACT OR LOWER POINT)on that, he/she get the list of subjects he/she is eligible to apply for.

E.g Enter your points:24

the output in the listview should give the following:
French:16
Management:22
English:24
Asian Language:10

I tried this but am stuck and could not complete the codes:

```
Course.java

public class Course {

private String name;
private int points;

public Course(String name, int points) {
    this.name = name;
    this.points = points;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public int getPoints() {
    return points;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return getName();
}
}

Course[] courses = new Course[]{
    new Course("Medicine", 30),
    new Course("Physics", 28),
    new Course("Math", 24),
    new Course("English", 20)
 };  


Button searchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_search);
searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
List<Course> courseList = new ArrayList<Course>(Arrays.asList(courses));
// initialize the adapter with courseList... //

// this code inside the Button's onClick                    
int points = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
for (Course c : courses) {
if (c.getPoints() <= points) {
    adapter.add(c);
}
}




course.xml

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="horizontal">
    <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Enter your points:"
            android:id="@+id/editText"/>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Search"
            android:id="@+id/btn_search"/>
</LinearLayout>

<ListView
        android:id="@+id/courseNames"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution as below -

1. MainActivity

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   ListView myList;
   EditText edtSearch;
   Button btnSearch;

   listAdapter adapter;
   ArrayList<Course> alSearchCourses;
   Course[] courses;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myList);
   edtSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtSearch);
   btnSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);

   courses = new Course[]{
           new Course("Medicine", 30),
           new Course("Physics", 28),
           new Course("Math", 24),
           new Course("English", 20)
   };

   adapter = new listAdapter(this, courses);
   myList.setAdapter(adapter);

   edtSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
       @Override
       public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
       }

       @Override
       public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
           if (count == 0) {
               adapter = new listAdapter(MainActivity.this, courses);
               myList.setAdapter(adapter);
           }
       }

       @Override
       public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
       }
   });

   btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

           alSearchCourses = new ArrayList<>();

           int points = Integer.parseInt(edtSearch.getText().toString());
           for (int i = 0; i < courses.length; i++) {

               Course c2 = courses[i];

               if (c2.getPoints() <= points) {
                   alSearchCourses.add(c2);
               }

           }

           Course searchCourses [] = new Course[alSearchCourses.size()];
           searchCourses = alSearchCourses.toArray(searchCourses);

           adapter = new listAdapter(MainActivity.this, searchCourses);
           myList.setAdapter(adapter);

       }

   });

   }
   }
   ```
2. listAdapter

   ```
   public class listAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

   Context context;
   Course[] courses;
   LayoutInflater inflater;

   public listAdapter(Context context, Course[] courses) {
   this.context = context;
   this.courses = courses;
   inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
   }

   @Override
   public int getCount() {
   return courses.length;
   }

   @Override
   public Object getItem(int position) {
   return null;
   }

   @Override
   public long getItemId(int position) {
   return 0;
   }

   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

   if(convertView == null){
       convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_layout, null);
   }

   TextView txtCourse = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtCourse);
   txtCourse.setText(courses[position].getName() + "-" +     courses[position].getPoints());

   return convertView;
   }
   }
   ```

Hope it helps :)