# how to allow only one radiobtton to be executed in a radiogroup inside a linear layout?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I am trying to place a radio group with 3 radio buttons inside a linear layout. My aim is to choose only one RadioButton inside the RadioGroup but, it is giving me an error that there are multiple root tags. Can someone figure out how to solve this?

file.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ok"

    android:id="@+id/textemail"/>

<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/one"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="one" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/two"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="two"
    />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/three"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="three" />

</RadioGroup>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textemail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="To:"
     />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextTo"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="khushi"/>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Comment:"
     />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextS3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="your comment"

    />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="email us "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:lines="10" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Send"
    android:textStyle="italic"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `RadioButton` should be within `RadioGroup`

Comment: radio group is not declared properly !!

Comment: i modifried my code above yet it is giving me wrong tag close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change below -

```
<RadioGroup
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

to

```
<RadioGroup
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/one"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="one" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/two"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="two"
    />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/three"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="three" />

</RadioGroup>
```

One of your Text is not in correct format change it as below -

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="ok:"
 />
```

to

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="ok:"
 />
```

One more error -

change below -

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

to

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

Comment: @khushi: simply remove </RadioButton> b4 </RadioGroup>. see my edit :)

Comment: that gave me again same error. this is giving error at linear layout too.

Comment: i remodified my code above now there is no error however all my textview and editview below the radio group disappeared. any solution?

Comment: @khushi: So sorry for not solving your issue in single hit. You need to modify 1 more thing and then its okay.

Comment: can you please my friend she has a problem and no one helped her.here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34659355/how-to-select-only-part-of-a-listview-based-on-different-requirements-by-the-use

Comment: u can answer her there she is in great trouble. thnks

Comment: Oh dear am sorry maybe i dont have enough reputations to do that!

Answer (score 3):

You immediately close your radiogroup:

```
<RadioGroup
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

This should be:

```
<RadioGroup
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"> // Note that there is no forward slash at the end
```

And you are not closing the `RadioGroup`:

`</RadioButton>` <-- This should be `</RadioGroup>`

Comment: i changed the code above as u said but it is giving me wrong closing tag and multipleroot tags. help me.

Comment: I see you added `</Radiogroup>`. You should have changed `</RadioButton>` into `</RadioGroup>`. In your case, you are closing the last radiobutton twice by `<RadioButton />` and `</RadioButton>`

Comment: i remodified my code above now there is no error however all my textview and editview below the radio group disappeared. any solution?

Comment: The `layout_height` of your RadioGroup is set to match_parent and is therefore taking up all the available space on the activity. Change to wrap_content and it should be OK

Answer (score 1):

Your RadioButton (views) should be children of the RadioGroup(view). By closing your RadioGroup using /> you declare the RadioButton(s) and the RadioGroup as children of the LinearLayout.

The Following should work.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Linearlayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="hello"
    android:id="@+id/textview"/>

<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/one"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="one" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/two"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="two"
    />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/three"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="three" />
</RadioButton>
</RadioGroup>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewllol"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textemail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="hi:"
     />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Texme"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="comment:"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Text2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="your comments"

    />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView45"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ok"
     />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextMessage"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:lines="10" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4785"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="send"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i changed the change as u said but it is giving me wrong closing tag and multipleroot tags. help me.

Answer (score 0):

You have one `</Radiobutton>` tag above `</Radiogroup>` that shouldn't be here. Just remove it to have :

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/one"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="one" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/two"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="two"
    />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/three"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="three" />
</RadioGroup>
```